# Train many neural networks and pick best one

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm working on a classification task, trying to reconstruct a network from paper. In that paper, they are talking about doing a train test split 300 times and training the network each time after they are taking the mean of all predictions from each network for specific input data.

So here's the question: What is the best option for doing that, I've already reconstructed their network and thinking about using a for loop and saving outputs of each network in a data frame but can't get it the right way.
Here's the code :

```
# Set X and Y for training

X = dum_bll_fsrq.drop(['type2', 'name', 'Type_is_bll', 'Type_is_fsrq'], axis = 1)
Y = dum_bll_fsrq.iloc[:,-2:]

# Train test split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, stratify = Y)

# Create model

model_two_neuron = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, input_shape=(15,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model_two_neuron.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])

# Train

model_two_neuron.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks to save the best weights for each of your models, then evaluate the best results saved by callbacks after training.
Here is a basic example, provided in the [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint):

```
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=...,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

EPOCHS = 10
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

# Model weights are saved at the end of every epoch, if it's the best seen
# so far.
model.fit(epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])

# The model weights (that are considered the best) are loaded into the model.
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. So if I get it right, when I use callbacks and doing a for loof of trainings and tests after all it will save only the best one?

Comment: Correct, it will safe the best one. You can also save more than that if you want more than the best model.

Comment: After the first evaluation it's skipping all the others because the evaluation of the last epoch of the first training is always better than the first epoch evaluation of the next network training, what can I do to compare the last epochs of networks?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663447/use-callbacks-to-pick-best-network
here's the code